# Call SignalR method in Swift (SwiftR)

Tags: ios, swift, signalr, swiftr

I want to use SignalR in my project, I don't know anything about working with signalR in swift, I am install SwiftR pod, but i don't know how call webService method, pass parameter to webService and get JSON result from webService, there is my simple code for connect to webService and starting connection but everything is wrong and connection is unsuccessful.
this is url : ￼http://s.ne***y.ir/
this is method that should call :
 Authentication_Code_Request(string Mobile, byte Method)
Method is 10 or 20
I should get this response : ￼
Message
￼Method
￼Code
￼Sender

there is my code :

```
var autHub: Hub!
    var connection: SignalR!
    //var name: String!

@IBAction func sendRequest(_ sender: Any) {

         connection = SignalR("http://s.ne***y.ir/")
        connection.signalRVersion = .v2_2_0

        print(connection.baseUrl)

        var methodString: String?
        methodString = "10"
        chatHub = Hub("autHub")
        chatHub.on("￼￼Authentication_Code_Request") { [weak self] args in
            if let mobile = args?[0] as? String, let method = args?[1] as? String, let mobiletext = self?.chatTextView.text, let mehodText = methodString {
                print(method)
                print(mobiletext)
                print(mehodText)
                print(mobile)
            }
        }
        connection.addHub(chatHub)

        connection.starting = { [weak self] in

            self?.button.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2745098174, green: 0.4862745106, blue: 0.1411764771, alpha: 1)
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have worked with SignalR, I can help with Objective C process. Not Swift

Comment: @AbhishekSharma no problem might help. thanks

Comment: Wait I am creating a swift App for you and sending you soon.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma thanks a lot.

Comment: I have attached a working copy. Please download that and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is SignalR objective C used in Swift using Bridging-Header

First, install Pods

pod 'SignalR-ObjC'

=======================================================

Add Objective C Classes name SignalRClassViewController.h and SignalRClassViewController.m

=======================================================
    SignalRClassViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SignalR_ObjC/SRClientTransportInterface.h>
#import <SignalR_ObjC/SRHubProxy.h>
#import <SignalR_ObjC/SRHubConnection.h>
#import <SignalR_ObjC/SRConnection.h>
#import <SignalR_ObjC/SRHubConnectionInterface.h>

@interface SignalRClassViewController : UIViewController<SRConnectionDelegate, SRHubConnectionInterface, SRClientTransportInterface>


// This method is used to have Single Instance. In the whole app, Life cycle makes sure you are using only one Instance of SignalR Class because of it one to one connection so we need listeners which continue to listen each time. 


+(SignalRClassViewController *)getInstance;


-(void)SignalRConnection;
-(void)SignalRStopCoonection;


// Write your Own Methods
-(void)assignUser;
-(void)GetWebActiveClients;
@end
```

=======================================================
SignalRClassViewController.m

```
#import "SignalRClassViewController.h"
@interface SignalRClassViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *array ;
}
@end

static SRHubProxy *chat = nil;
static SRHubConnection *hubConnection = nil;

@implementation SignalRClassViewController

static SignalRClassViewController *instance = nil;


+(SignalRClassViewController *)getInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(instance==nil)
        {
            instance= [SignalRClassViewController new];
            [instance iniHUB];

        }else{
            [instance iniHUB];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}



-(void) iniHUB{


    if(hubConnection == nil){
        NSDictionary *parameters;



        parameters = @{ @"UserId": @"121",
                        @"UserToken": @"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJNeUhhc2giOiIyYzg5ODVmZC1jZDkyLTRjNzItOWNmYi01MWIyMWY1Y2FjZGQiLCIyYzg5ODVmZC1jZDkyLTRjNzItOWNmYi01MWIyMWY1Y2FjZGQiOjEyMX0.bDnuuroAmXvh-kifWN5jpJaSJVnMipuMD4QXon2lB-w"
                        };
        hubConnection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURLString:@"http://web.abc.......xyz.it" queryString:parameters];
        // parameters if you want to authenticate connection
        else  use  hubConnection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURLString:@"http://web.abc.......xyz.it"];

        [hubConnection setDelegate:self];

        chat = [hubConnection createHubProxy:@"yourHubName"];

      // Add event for which you want to active your listener when server trigger it
        [chat on:@"ResponseAssignUserDevice" perform:self selector:@selector(responseAssignUserDevice:)];

        [chat on:@"GetWebActiveClients" perform:self selector:@selector(ResponseGetWebActiveClients:)];

        [hubConnection start];
        // Start Connection
    }
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark SRConnection Delegate

- (void)SRConnectionDidClose:(id<SRConnectionInterface>)connection{
    NSLog(@"Connection close");
    [self removeChatObserver];
    [self iniHUB];

}

-(void) removeChatObserver{
    if(chat!=nil){
        chat=nil;
        hubConnection=nil;
    }
}

- (void)SRConnectionDidSlow:(id<SRConnectionInterface>)connection{
    NSLog(@"Reconnect Slow");

}
- (void)SRConnectionWillReconnect:(id<SRConnectionInterface>)connection{
    NSLog(@"Reconnected");
}

-(void)SignalRStopCoonection{
    // Start the connection
    if(hubConnection!= nil){
        [hubConnection stop];
        [self removeChatObserver];
    }

}


-(void)SRConnectionDidOpen:(SRHubConnection*)connection{
    NSLog(@"SR Conection open");
    // When Connection is open call AssignUser
    [self assignUser];


}


-(void)assignUser{

    NSDictionary *parameters;
    parameters = @{ @"UserId": @"121",
                    @"DeviceType": @"Mobile",
                    @"WebToken" : @"NA",
                    @"DeviceOS" : @"iPhone",
                    @"BrowserName" : @"NA"
                    };


    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array addObject:parameters];
    [chat invoke:@"AssignUserDevice" withArgs:array];
    // This will  invoke  AssignUserDevice which is on server and you have added it selector when server will reponse on this name responseAssignUserDevice



}

- (void)responseAssignUserDevice:(NSString *)message {
    // Print the message when it comes in
    NSLog(@"SR msg %@",message);
}


-(void)GetWebActiveClients{
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"121"]];
    [chat invoke:@"GetWebActiveClients" withArgs:array];

}

- (void)ResponseGetWebActiveClients:(NSString *)message
{
    // Print the message when it comes in
    NSLog(@"SR msg responseGetArticleByDate  %@",message);
}




@end
```

=======================================================

ViewController.Swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func assignUser(_ sender: Any) {
      SignalRClassViewController.getInstance().assignUser()
    }

    @IBAction func GetWebActiveClients(_ sender: Any) {
       SignalRClassViewController.getInstance().getWebActiveClients()
    }
}
```

Please check [code here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gscoxec7bgd3zwb/SignalR%20Swift.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Where specified parameters that must be sent when call client method ?

Comment: When you are calling client method from the server at that time you can send it via message String that will be a Dictionary or array. Simple take it as String and convert into needed   Dictionary or array.

Comment: @ Abhishek Sharma Sorry for my late Yes, this was quite true

Comment: If you want in swift then I can try to build an example for that as well

Comment: in my server methods Code_Request(string Mobile, byte Method) i should send byte as method parameter what means byte type in this case ?